# PrestaShop - Overriding a controller does not work

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to override a controller in PrestaShop

```
<?php

class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore{

    public function initContent()
    {

        parent::initContent();
    }
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        echo "datbase";
        die;
    }
}

?>
```

The file containing my Override is located in:

`projectname/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php`

But my override does not work.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer for PrestaShop 1.7.x**

In PrestaShop 1.7.x versions, the class_index.php file is now located in `/var/cache/prod`:

[image: PrestaShop 1.7 class_index.php file]

Don't forget to delete this file in case you've just added a new override, otherwise it won't work.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it now from researching somethings

I found the solution:

You should delete the file "class_index.php" in cache folder.